# getting query parameters from URL in laravel 7.1

Tags: laravel, routes

Just as a learning exercise, I'm creating a REST API in Laravel 7.1. I'm having trouble figuring out how to parse the query string parameters in route methods. I've read over the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing), and it shows how to add parameters into the path:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

However I don't see where you can get query parameters from the request URL. In my toy code, I want to add a route to add a new car to inventory:

```
Route::post('/inventory/add/{make}/{model}/{year}', function ($make, $model, $year) {
    return \App\Inventory::create($model, $color, $trim, $accessories);
});
```

I want to specify parameters such as color, trim, and accessories through the query string, like so:

```
http://example.com/inventory/add/ford/focus/2020?color=red&trim=sport&accessories=chrome-wheels
```

How do I get the query parameters out of the `Route::post` method?

**Edit** I suppose this architecture may not be the optimal way of adding this extra information, but since I am trying to learn laravel, I am using it as an example. I am interested in learning how to get the query parameters moreso than how to improve the architecture of this learning example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `Route::post` you don't need set the parameters in route. Just use:

```
Route::post("your-route", "YourControllerController@doSomeThing");
```

So, in `app/Http/Controllers/YourControllerController.php` file:

```
class YourControllerController extends Controller {

public function doSomeThing(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->input('param1');
    echo $request->input('param2');
    echo $request->input('param3');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to inject the request instance into your handler (whatever a closure or controller method) and then ask for your parameters.

```php
$color = $request->query('color', 'default-color');

//And so on...
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input